# Faster way to add values to existing dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries

```
#Initialize the dictionary
myDict=dict()
for f in ncp:
    myDict[f]={}
    for t in ncp:
        myDict[f][t] = {}
```

And now I go through and add a value to the lowest level (which happens to be a dictionary key and value of None), like so, but my current method is very slow

```
for s in subsetList:
    stIndex = 0
    for f in list(allNodes.intersection(set(s)))
            for t in list(allNodes.difference(set( allNodes.intersection(s)))):
                myDict[f][t]['st_'+str(stIndex)]=None
    stIndex+=1
```

I try to do it with principles of comprehension, but I fail miserably because the examples I find for comprehension are creating the dictionary, not iterating through an already existing one to add.  My attempt to do so wont even 'compile':

```
myDict[f][t]['st_'+str(stIndex)]
    for f in list(allNodes.intersection(set(s)))
       for t in list(allNodes.difference(set( allNodes.intersection(s)))) = None
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the general problem you're trying to solve? Comprehensions create objects so no, they're not going to be a good way to add something to an existing object.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by 'it's too slow' and what you expect/want?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and at least describe what/how the code you have and is too slow does/works. Also what are `subsetlist` and `allNones`? We're not mind readers.

Comment: Creation of the dict takes less than a second, but iterating through to build up the content in the dict takes over a minute.  I'll try to add more detail to the question later today.  Thanks all

Comment: Is `allNodes.intersection(set(s))` different from `allNodes.intersection(s)`? Regardless, you're calling the latter potentially many more times than necessary since its value doesn't change each iteration of the inner `for` loop. Is it necessary to convert its result to a `set` before passing it as an argument in the `allNodes.difference(set( allNodes.intersection(s)))` expression?

Comment: I took the set() commands out, martin.  Don' think it helped bc runtime stayed the exact same.

        for f in list(allNodes.intersection(s)):
            for t in list(allNodes.difference(allNodes.intersection(s))):
                VarShadowPrices[f][t]['st_'+str(stIndex)]=None

Comment: @user3431083 You don't need to create a new list to iterate over at each step.

Answer (score 0):

I would write your code like this:

```
myDict = {}
for i, s in enumurate(subsetList):
    tpl = ('st_%d' % (i,), None) # Used to create a new {'st_n': None} later
    x = allNodes.intersection(s)
    for f in x:
        myDict[f] = {}
        for t in allNodes.difference(x):
            myDict[f][t] = dict([tpl])
```

This cuts down on the number of new objects you need to create, as well as initializing `myDict` on-demand.

Comment: Thanks chepner, but this made it run slower per my testing.  A lot slower actually.

Comment: Are you including the time it took you to initialize `myDict` in the first part of your code?

Comment: Yes, by alot slower I mean i left it running for 30 min and it still wasnt done

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster...

```
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(dict)
for f, t in  product(ncp, repeat=2):
    myDict[f][t] = {}
    for s in subsetList:
        myDict[f][t]['st_'+str(stIndex)] = None
```

Or if the innermost key level is the same each time...

```
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict

innerDict = {}
for s in subsetList: 
    innerDict['st_'+str(stIndex)] = None

mydict = defaultdict(dict)
for f, t in  product(ncp, repeat=2):
    myDict[f][t] = innerDict.copy()
```

But I'm not sure whether creating a copy of the innermost dictionary is faster than iterating through your subsetList and creating the new dictionary each time. You'd need to time the two options.

Comment: Thanks Sasha, I will test and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sasha, I think a problem with your solution is that f and t are a function of s and I don't see that happening in yours.  For example ncp may be [a,b,c] and so if s1 is [a,b] then for the first iteration of s you will have f = a and t = c because c results from allNodes.difference(s).  Basically, f means 'from', and t means 'to'.  We are trying to go "from" s "to" everything not in s, one element of s at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here with a theory on best approach after much trial:  The final result is myDict and it is a function of 2 elements: allNodes and subsetList, both of which are effectively static tables imported from SQL at the start of my program.  So, why not calculate myDict once and store it in SQL and import it also.  So instead of rebuilding it every time the program runs which takes 2 minutes, it is just a couple second pyodbc read.  I know its kind of a cop out, but it works for the time being.